# calculate centered absolute div inside relative

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using 2 Javscript methods to position a hovering button inside a static element on my page. The button that is centered is inputted inside the first element and uses position absolute. The code I'm using to get the parent element measurements:

```
// calculate if the element is in the visible window
function elementVisibleRect(element) {
    element = $(element);
    var rect = {
        top: Math.round(element.offset().top),
        left: Math.round(element.offset().left),
        width: Math.round(element.outerWidth()),
        height: Math.round(element.outerHeight())
    };
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var scrollBottom = scrollTop + windowHeight;
    var elementBottom = Math.round(rect.height + rect.top);

    if (scrollTop < rect.top && scrollBottom > elementBottom) {
        return rect;
    }
    if (scrollTop > rect.top) {
        rect.top = scrollTop;
    }
    if (scrollBottom < elementBottom) {
        rect.height = scrollBottom - rect.top;
    } else {
        rect.height = windowHeight - (scrollBottom - elementBottom);
    }
    return rect;
}
```

and for using this information and centering the button inside

```
// center the element based on visible screen-frame
function elementPosition (element) {
    var visibleRect = elementVisibleRect(element);
    $('.editHoverButton').css({
        top: visibleRect.top + ((visibleRect.height / 2) - ($('.editHoverButton').outerHeight() / 2)),
        left: visibleRect.left + (visibleRect.width / 2) - ($('.editHoverButton').outerWidth() / 2)
    });
}
```

Now my problem is that a third party library requires the parent DIV to change position from the browser default "static" to "relative" which breaks my calculations in the second function.

It might be late, but no matter what I try I can't seem to figure out how to get this working for when the parent element has position set to relative. I can't seem to get the maths quite right, and my head is beginning to hurt. Any suggestions?

**EDIT - ADDED JSFIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/RhTY6/

Comment: You can try using the !important declaration to override the 3rd party's CSS. Just be sure you are nailing the DOM properly.
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules

Comment: Maybe I didn't made it very clear but I need it to stay position relative for other functionality, and can't change it.

Comment: Can you post a sample on Fiddle along with HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: made it worked with your CSS and HTML (relative and absolute positioning) by altering the Script only.

The horizontal axis calcs were completely missing (I've applied the same calcs you applied to the vertical axis).

I've added some data and a ruler to help you finish the job: as you can see, it is (and it was, in your original fiddle) not *perfectly* centered (obviously you need to look at it when the container is smaller than the viewport), but this will be easy to work out.

<kbd>[Running Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r9Kgr/)</kbd>

Try to resize the fiddle window and to scroll both vertically and horizontally to see it works.

```
function elementVisibleRect(element) {
    $("#data").html("");

    element = $(element);
    var rect = {
        top: Math.round(element.offset().top),
        left: Math.round(element.offset().left),
        width: Math.round(element.outerWidth()),
        height: Math.round(element.outerHeight())
    };
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var scrollBottom = scrollTop + windowHeight;
    var elementBottom = Math.round(rect.height + rect.top);

    var scrollLeft = $(window).scrollLeft();
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    var scrollRight = scrollLeft + windowWidth;
    var elementRight = Math.round(rect.width + rect.left);


    addData("rect.top", rect.top);
    addData("rect.left", rect.left);
    addData("rect.width", rect.width);
    addData("rect.height", rect.height);
    addData("scrollTop", scrollTop);
    addData("windowHeight", windowHeight);
    addData("scrollBottom", scrollBottom);
    addData("elementBottom", elementBottom);
    addData("scrollLeft", scrollLeft);
    addData("windowWidth", windowWidth);
    addData("scrollRight", scrollRight);
    addData("elementRight", elementRight);


    if (rect.top < scrollTop) {
        rect.top = scrollTop;
    }
    if (scrollBottom < rect.top < scrollTop) {
        rect.top = scrollTop;
    }
    if (scrollBottom < elementBottom) {
        rect.height = scrollBottom - rect.top;
    } else {
        rect.height = windowHeight - (scrollBottom - elementBottom);
    }

    if (rect.left < scrollLeft) {
        rect.left = scrollLeft;
    }
    if (scrollRight < rect.left < scrollLeft) {
        rect.left = scrollLeft;
    }
    if (scrollRight < elementRight) {
        rect.width = scrollRight - rect.left;
    } else {
        rect.width = windowWidth - (scrollRight - elementRight);
    }

    return rect;
}
```

Comment: Not bad, can't believe I missed to try that. Still plenty of issues though, doesn't really stay centered in viewable area at all times as can be seen in this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/RhTY6/2/

Comment: Yeah, you should adjust your script. IF your div is bigger than viewalbe area, then fixed will work (with no script at all, just css centering), because it works with the viewport. IF your div is smaller than the viewable area, then your script will work, because it correctly calculate positions. The grey areas are when your div is larger than viewable area in one axis (eg. horizontally), and smaller in the other (eg. vertically). That is the tricky part...

Comment: The problem with `fixed`is that it is relative to the scrollable window, meaning that if you scroll while the button is visible, it doesn't scroll with the page. [`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/RhTY6/5/)

Comment: I know, but since he always want it to be centered (to the container if smaller, or to the viewport if bigger), it could fit his needs (I was meaning that in the answer).

Comment: Great, almost there! I called for recalculations on scroll event in my modified test at:
http://jsfiddle.net/r9Kgr/2/
which seems to work, but i still have a small problem when scrolling to the left, which seems to change the hover buttons width?

Comment: +1 for now, will probably accept as correct answer very soon, especially if i could get help with the hovering width on side-scrolling.

Comment: I don't know why it does that, but you can fix it with `var width = $('.editHoverButton').width();` and `width: width` in the `elementPosition(element)` function. [`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/r9Kgr/4/)

Answer (score 3):

Elements with `absolute` positioning are removed from the natural flow (e.g. they don't leave a space where they were) **and positioned relative to their first parent with non-`static` positioning**. Since the positioning of the right-hand box is `relative` (not `static`), you can position the button with `top: 50%;` and `left: 50%;`. This will make the top-left corner at the center of the parent. Then all you have to do is subtract half the element's height and width from the position, using `margin-top` and `margin-left`. This is much simpler than what you were doing, as you can see below:

JavaScript:

```
function elementPosition() {
    $('.editHoverButton').css('margin-top', 0 - $('.editHoverButton').outerHeight() / 2);
    $('.editHoverButton').css('margin-left', 0 - $('.editHoverButton').outerWidth() / 2);
};
```

CSS:

```
.editHoverButton {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  background-color: #00bb00;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

Nothing else has to change except to remove `this` from the `elementPosition()` function.

[<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/RhTY6/3/) (Notice that the left one no longer works. This is because it is positioned `static`.)

**EDIT--Using the same basic idea, this method should work:**

The problem is that you have take the top and left positions of the element when defining `rect`. on the positioning calculations. Changing those to `0` (not the best method, but it works) fixes the problem for `relative` elements.

[<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/RhTY6/8/) (Notice that the left one now **does** work. This is because it is positioned at 0,0 anyway.)

**EDIT--This will work when the page scrolls:**

This sets the container in a variable so that when the page scrolls, it can be repositioned automatically.

[<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/RhTY6/63/)

Comment: All right, but this works to always center the button in the middle of the container div; if the container div is bigger than the viewport, OP wants to center it in the viewport. Try to lower the height of the fiddle and you will see that. He is in a mixed case, has to apply fixed or absolute depending on viewport-contained or viewport-overflowing status of the container, or write a more complex script.

Comment: Hmmm...I see what you mean. I'll get on that.

Comment: OK, think I got it this time.

Comment: agree, +1 for effort. but I think Andrea's version comes closer to what I had in mind.

Comment: Sorry, my second demo link was wrong (it was same as the first).

Comment: Yeah, but it's very strange when the element is not positioned at the beginning of the axis of scrolling--the button goes way to the right or the bottom. Still can't figure this math out completely, but when yours is not positioned at the top at the beginning, there is a jump when you start scrolling. [`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/r9Kgr/5/)

Comment: Thanks for both your help!  I accepted Andrea's answer, but upvoted all Ians to try and reward equally.